# How to specify encoding in python?

Tags: python

I'm seeing two different standards and am not sure if one is deprecated.  Is there a way to test the encoding or verifying one way vs the other?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: What do you mean with "to test the encoding or verifying one way vs the other"? Whether the stated encoding matches the encoding in the file?

Comment: @Wooble, kinda abuse of your buttons since the question could be understood differently. See my outstanding question.

Comment: @Kay: feel free to vote to reopen. What the OP is asking was clear to me.